# Is it possible to construct an object so that it throws an error when its keys are requested?

Tags: javascript, object, metaprogramming, interceptor

Imagine I have the following code:

```
const object = {};
// an error should be thrown
object.property.someMethod();
// an error should be thrown
object.foo;
```

Is it possible to throw an error when `someMethod()` is called or if any other non-existing property is called?

I guess that I need to do something with it's prototype, to throw an Error. However, I'm not sure what exactly I should do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with a [`handler.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) trap:

```js
const object = new Proxy({}, {
  get (target, key) {
    throw new Error(`attempted access of nonexistent key \`${key}\``);
  }
})

object.foo
```

If you want to modify an existing object with this behavior, you can use [`Reflect.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/has) to check for property existence and determine whether to forward the access using [`Reflect.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get) or `throw`:

```js
const object = new Proxy({
  name: 'Fred',
  age: 42,
  get foo () { return this.bar }
}, {
  get (target, key, receiver) {
    if (Reflect.has(target, key)) {
      return Reflect.get(target, key, receiver)
    } else {
      throw new Error(`attempted access of nonexistent key \`${key}\``)
    }
  }
})

console.log(object.name)
console.log(object.age)
console.log(object.foo)
```

Comment: If using this on an already existing object, e.g., `{name: "Fred", age: 42}` then the `get` handler needs to just check if the fetched property is in the target `get(target, property) { if (!(property in target)) { throw new Error(); } else return target[property]; }`

Comment: Might be worth forwarding the context to the Reflect.get method as well?

Comment: @Michael good point, in case a getter accesses a nonexistent property on the object.